# Encontrar valor de célula em Planilha - VBA

Tags: vba

Poderiam me dar um help?

Preciso fazer um código que me mostre se o valor de uma determinada célula está em uma planilha de dados em outra aba e, caso esteja, identifique a linha em questão e a apague para que eu possa sobrescreve-la com outras informações.

Alguém consegue me dar uma luz de por onde começar?

O que eu tenho até agora é isso, mas está dando errado (eu finalizo o código com o preenchimento das colunas e o fechamento do if):

Sub Update_Form()

Dim Project_ID As String
Dim Linha As String

Project_ID = Worksheets("Form_Update").Range("c11")

If Project_ID = Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range("A:A").Find(Sheets("Form_Update").Range("c11").Value) Then

Set Linha = Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range("A:A").Find(Sheets("Form_Update").Range("c11").Value).Row
Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range(Linha & ":" & Linha).Delete

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Primeiramente, não utilize mais de uma declaração `Dim` na mesma linha, faça

```
Dim Project_ID As String 
Dim Linha As Integer
```

Use a propriedade `Text` do objeto `Range` para capturar o texto de uma célula, pode-se utilizar a propriedade `Value` também.

```
Project_ID = Worksheets("Form_Update").Range("c11").Text
```

O comando `set` só é utilizado para igualar referências de objetos, como `Worksheet` ou `Range`. Nesse caso, como você quer apenas a linha, que é um inteiro, pode-se utilizar simplesmente o sinal de igualdade.

```
linha = Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range("A:A").Find(project_ID, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
```

Por fim, utilize o método `ClearContents` para apagar o conteúdo da linha e sobrescrevê-la (deletar a linha traz o conteúdo da linha imediatamente inferior e pode te causar problemas).

```
Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range("A" & linha).EntireRow.ClearContents
```

Segue abaixo o código completo.

```
Sub Update_Form()

On Error GoTo Erro

Dim project_ID As String
Dim linha As Integer

project_ID = Worksheets("Form_Update").Range("C11").Text
linha = Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range("A:A").Find(project_ID, lookat:=xlWhole).Row
Sheets("Pipe - YTD").Range("A" & linha).EntireRow.ClearContents

End Sub
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).